# change value og variables in kv file

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

In my kv file i have a varible:

```
#:set bg_color 1,1,1,.7
```

Is it posible to change this variable with button action?

```
on_press:
   *some command that changes the variable*
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot change a variable in a `kv` file that is created by `#:set`. That variable only exists when the `kv` file is being parsed (normally just once when the app is being created). I suspect what you really should use is a [ColorProperty](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.ColorProperty). You can use such a `Property` in your `kv` file, and change its value by a `Button` click.

Comment: thx @John-Anderson for the answer ... i hoped i could and that have led me to the next question to solve my problem ... I have posted it here so it would not make this thread confusing (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67522460/how-to-target-canvas-before-in-kv).

I really appreciate your inputs inputs :)